# Python - Plot lower and upper bound for a small region

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have 4 numpy arrays

```
true = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
pred = np.array([3.1,4.1,5.1])
lower = np.array([3,4,5])
upper = np.array([3.2,4.2,5.2])
```

where the `pred`,`lower` and `upper` are the median predictions, the lower bound and the upper bound of the predictions respectively (only for the last 3 timepoints, not the first 2 timepoints).

I am not sure how to plot all 4 arrays in 1 plots. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this? If the plots overlap a lot, you could add an `alpha` parameter.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

true = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
pred = np.array([3.1,4.1,5.1])
lower = np.array([2.9,3.9,4.9])
upper = np.array([3.2,4.2,5.2])
xs = range(1,6)

f, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(xs[2:], lower, color='limegreen', marker='o', label='lower', lw=0.5, markersize=2)
ax.plot(xs[2:], pred, color='aqua', marker='o', label='pred', markersize=2)
ax.plot(xs[2:], upper, color='dodgerblue', marker='o', label='upper', lw=0.5, markersize=2)
ax.plot(xs, true, color='crimson', marker='o', label='true')
ax.fill_between(xs[2:], lower, upper, color='gold', alpha=0.3, label='region')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Answer (score 1):

To have everything on one plot, you can use function `plot` from `matplotlib`.
To add multiple lines on one plot, you need to provide pairs of `x` and `y`. This code should explain it:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

true = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
pred = np.array([3.1,4.1,5.1])
lower = np.array([3,4,5])
upper = np.array([3.2,4.2,5.2])

x = np.arange(1, 6, 1)
x_med = np.arange(3,6,1)

plt.plot(x, true, x_med, pred, x_med, lower, x_med, upper)
plt.show()
```